# Using DB2 Spatial Types in .Net

Tags: c#, geometry, db2, ado.net, geospatial

Is there any support for DB2 spatial types as parameters in .Net? I can't see any mention of any geo-spatial types in the documentation and no mention of it anywhere else. I could probably roll my own if someone knows the parameter format that would be used to pass the values in.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this, there is next to no information. You can query for geospatial types and the provider returns them as Well Known Text strings, which isn't terrible, but the SRID is missing. Some creative use of ST_SRID and ST_GeomToText should help but it's kinda wild west to get this working.